# хочу сделать чтобы переключатель видимости блока при нажатии на кнопку на чистом js. почему мой код не работает

Tags: javascript

```
let div = document.querySelector("div");

let btn = document.querySelector("button");


btn.onclick = function () {

    if (div.style.display = 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};



div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>js practic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/1.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div></div>
    <button>Go</button>

    <script src="/js practic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: внутри условия - присвоение : `if (div.style.display = 'none')`

Comment: == работает спасибо

Comment: не за что, но почитайте про разницу между `===` и `==` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F